# How to loop until user's input satisfies a condition?

Tags: java, loops, matrix, variable-assignment, user-input

So I'm writing a program that prompts the user for the dimensions of two Matrices, creates two random matrices based on these dimensions, and then multiplies them together.

I'm having some trouble with the first part. I want the program to keep asking the user for the dimensions until they enter dimensions that can be multiplied (# of columns in first matrix = # of rows in second matrix).

But how do I re-assign the new entered values to the same variables??
Here's what I have so far:

```
public class Multiply {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

                Scanner myScanner;
                myScanner = new Scanner( System.in );

                System.out.println("Enter the number of rows in Matrix #1: ");
                System.out.println("Enter the number of columns in Matrix #1: ");
                System.out.println("Enter the number of rows in Matrix #2: ");
                System.out.println("Enter the number of columns in Matrix #2: ");

                int mOne = myScanner.nextInt();
                int nOne = myScanner.nextInt();
                int mTwo = myScanner.nextInt();
                int nTwo = myScanner.nextInt();

                if(mOne<=0 || mTwo<=0 || nOne<=0 || nTwo<=0){
                        System.out.println("Sorry, these are not valid dimensional inpupts");
                        System.exit(0);
                }

                while (nOne!=mTwo){
                        System.out.println("Sorry these matrices cannot be multiplied, please enter new dimensions");
                }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a do... while loop

```
 public class Multiply {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner myScanner;
            myScanner = new Scanner( System.in );

            int mOne =0;
            int nOne = 0;
            int mTwo = 0;
            int nTwo = 0; 

            do {
                System.out.println("Enter the number of rows in Matrix #1: ");
                System.out.println("Enter the number of columns in Matrix #1: ");
                System.out.println("Enter the number of rows in Matrix #2: ");
                System.out.println("Enter the number of columns in Matrix  #2: ");

                mOne = myScanner.nextInt();
                nOne = myScanner.nextInt();
                mTwo = myScanner.nextInt();
                nTwo = myScanner.nextInt();

                if(mOne<=0 || mTwo<=0 || nOne<=0 || nTwo<=0){
                    System.out.println("Sorry, these are not valid     dimensional inpupts");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                if (nOne != mTwo) {
                      System.out.println("Sorry these matrices cannot be     multiplied, please enter new dimensions");
                }

               } while (nOne!=mTwo);



            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to "while" on the condition:

```
public class Multiply {  
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

    Scanner myScanner;
    myScanner = new Scanner( System.in );

    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows in Matrix #1: ");
    System.out.println("Enter the number of columns in Matrix #1: ");
    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows in Matrix #2: ");
    System.out.println("Enter the number of columns in Matrix #2: ");

    int mOne = myScanner.nextInt();
    int nOne = myScanner.nextInt();
    int mTwo = myScanner.nextInt();
    int nTwo = myScanner.nextInt();

    while(mOne<=0 || mTwo<=0 || nOne<=0 || nTwo<=0){
        System.out.println("Sorry, these are not valid dimensional inpupts");
        mOne = myScanner.nextInt();
        nOne = myScanner.nextInt();
        mTwo = myScanner.nextInt();
        nTwo = myScanner.nextInt();
    }

...
}
```

It's the same with the other condition you need to apply on your input data.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the check with a do-while loop.

```
boolean firstRun = true;
do{
     if(firstRun)
           //print some errormessage here
     else 
          firstRun = false;
     //read the values here
}while(mOne<=0 || mTwo<=0 || nOne<=0 || nTwo<=0);
```

Comment: I think you want `if(!firstRun)`, because as it is you are printing error messages on the first run.

Comment: exactly. you could aswell replace this by a `while` loop, read the values for the first time before entering the loop and print an errormessage as soon as you enter the whileloop

Comment: How it is now, this will only print an error message once, is that how you intended it to be? What if the user enters an invalid choice more than once?

Comment: oops, sry, i made a little mistake `if(firstRun)` should actually be `if(!firstRun)`

Comment: I'm glad we can finally agree on something today =D

Answer (score 0):

When collecting input do the following:

```
int mOne = 0;
do{
  mOne = myScanner.nextInt();
}while(/*mOne is what you want*/);
```

This will loop until the answer given is what you want. You can also do this to post an error:

```
int mOne = 0;
    do{
      mOne = myScanner.nextInt();
      if(/*mOne is not what you want*/){
         //Tell user
      }else{
        break;
      }
    }while(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the while loop at the end, suspend the entire code in the while loop:

```
       do{        // Put the while loop here
            Scanner myScanner;
            myScanner = new Scanner( System.in );

            System.out.println("Enter the number of rows in Matrix #1: ");
            int mOne = myScanner.nextInt();    // Also, I suggest doing this to have
                                               // to have the input immediately after the
                                               // print statement.
            System.out.println("Enter the number of columns in Matrix #1: ");
            int nOne = myScanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the number of rows in Matrix #2: ");
            int mTwo = myScanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the number of columns in Matrix #2: ");
            int nTwo = myScanner.nextInt();






            if(mOne<=0 || mTwo<=0 || nOne<=0 || nTwo<=0){
                    System.out.println("Sorry, these are not valid dimensional inpupts");
                    System.exit(0);
            }


                    System.out.println("Sorry these matrices cannot be multiplied, please enter new dimensions");
        }while (nOne!=mTwo);
```